# Userform to fiill multiple sheets with "with"

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with my code. I need to update multiple sheets with one userform. However, my code keeps giving me error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub AddItem_Click()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim r1 As Long
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sheet4 As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("Sheet1", "Sheet4")
        r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        r1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       .Range("A" & r) = Me.txtFN
       .Range("A" & r1) = Me.txtFN
       .Range("B" & r) = Me.txtLN
```

Comment: What are the errors, and on what lines?

Comment: Create a `Private Sub` that accepts a single `w As Worksheet` and updates it. Call that sub once for each sheet to update. Alternatively, have a `For Each` loop over `Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet4"))` and put that code inside it.

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do with a collection of worksheets. In particular, how would it know that `r` is meant (presumably) for Sheet1 and `r1` is meant (presumably) for Sheet2? You need to loop through the worksheets.

Comment: This line probably can't evaluate on a worksheet array: `r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count)`. Also, worth noting that your `r` and `r1` are the same expression, redundant.

Comment: @DavidZemens How do I differentiate this?

Comment: @Mushiesmu `r` will be the last row for whatever the current sheet in the loop is; `r1` will just be a copy of that.

Answer (score 1):

The `Worksheets` property takes a single parameter, not a list of sheet names; you need to wrap the list of sheet names with an `Array(...)` call to feed it with more than a single sheet name.

```
With Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet4"))
```

But doing that will only make the `Worksheets` call succeed - it still won't return the object you're expecting to work with.

A `With` block holds a reference to an object. In this case, the object class is `Excel.Sheets`, which is a *collection of sheets*.

A *collection of* worksheets doesn't have a `Range` property; you can't treat it as you would a single `Worksheet`.

Assuming you mean to apply that logic to all `Worksheets` objects in the collection, you need to loop through the worksheets in that collection.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet4"))
    With ws
        r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ...
    End With
Next
```

Comment: This solution worked. However, it is copying everything now to both sheets instead of selected items. What I am having trouble with is transferring selective data.

Comment: @Mushiesmu I couldn't infer that requirement from your post - all you said was you needed to "update multiple sheets"; I don't know what your conditions need to be, but if some things need to be conditional, make them so, using `If` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but try something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddItem_Click()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim iLRow As Long, iC As Long, iErr As Long
    Dim aSheets As Variant: aSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet4")

    For iC = LBound(aSheets) To UBound(aSheets)
        Err.Clear
        iErr = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(aSheets(iC))
        iErr = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0

        If iErr = 0 Then
            With oWS
                iLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & iLRow) = "Test"
                .Range("B" & iLRow) = "Test2"
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That will work - but if there are e.g. 180 worksheets in the workbook, iterating them all when you're only interested in a handful isn't particularly efficient. OP was on the right track with `Worksheets({multiple sheet names})`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: true. Good shout. Did this in 2 mins without fully thinking it through. Could exit once the sheets are populated but your `Array` solution is much more efficient

Comment: Related reading: [Introducing the for-if anti-pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=8793)

Comment: @GSerg: :) thanks. I did know about the use of `Array` of sheets in this instance but like I said, I did it quickly and didn't think it through. However, my only concern with using the array is that: what happens if a user deletes one of the sheets? Now you are referencing a sheet that doesn't exist. Maybe I'm wrong but just a thought

Comment: @Zac That would be very difficult to arrange because VBA is single threaded and the user interface is blocked while the macro is running. If you manage to have it done by spamming `DoEvents` (I'm not even sure that would let the user enough freedom to delete a sheet), then most likely you will have an unusable instance of a `Worksheet` (not `Nothing`, but accessing any properties results in "Run-time error 800401A8 - Automation error" - same can be done to a `Range`).

Comment: @GSerg: I wasn't referring to doing this during the execution. I was thinking more in terms of, in the future, if a user deleted/renames either the `Sheet1` or `Sheet4` and the macro is triggered after this action, I'm pretty sure you would get a `Subscript out of range` error as the referenced sheet doesn't exist in the workbook anymore

Comment: @Zac Yes, you would get the error. Then again, if in your program it is okay if some sheets you want to process do not exist, then you'd process the sheets one by one, but instead of looping over all existing sheets you'd call `Worksheets("name")` several times and handle the exception as needed.

Comment: @GSerg yes. I think actual solution is somewhere in the middle. As you suggested, one could reference the specific sheets and handle the error that way

Comment: @GSerg: Based on our comments, changed my answer slightly :)